# Почему космические корабли именно «бороздят» просторы Вселенной?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, значение, метафора

В фильме «Операция „Ы“ и другие приключения Шурика» (новелла «Напарник») заучит фраза в адрес ленивого работника:

> «В то время, как наши космические корабли бороздят просторы
> Вселенной…»

В Словаре русского языка РАН Евгеньевой в прямом смысле:

> БОРОЗДИ́ТЬ, -зжу́, -зди́шь; несов., перех.
>
> 1. (сов. взбороздить). Прорезывать, проводить борозды. *Здесь все шесть плугов бригады --- дружно бороздили землю, откидывая тяжелые
>    маслянистые пласты чернозема.* Лаптев, «Заря».

> БОРОЗДА́, -ы́, вин. бо́розду и борозду́, мн. бо́розды, боро́зд, -а́м,
> ж.
>
> 1. Длинный прорез, глубокая черта, проведенная на поверхности земли плугом или другим пахотным орудием. *Распаханная земля густо чернела
>    жирными бороздами.* Короленко, Марусина заимка.

Таким образом, бороздить — это прорезать борозды, а борозды — это длинный прорезы, проведённые на поверхности земли плугом или другим пахотным орудием.

Это в прямом значении.

Но как же от такого прямого значения дошли до метафоры про космические корабли, которые «бороздят» просторы вселенной?

В том же словаре есть ещё такое значение бороздить:

> 2. Пересекать в различных направлениях. *Судя по морщинам, бороздившим его лоб ---, думы его были напряженны, мучительны.* Чехов, Лошадиная
>    фамилия. *Лил дождь, черное небо бороздили молнии.* Вересаев, Издали.

Отсюда следует, что:

*«В то время, как наши космические корабли **бороздят** просторы Вселенной…»*

Можно понимать как:

*«В то время, как наши космические корабли **пересекают в различных направлениях** просторы Вселенной…»*

Но это странный переносный смысл слова «бороздить».

Давайте посмотрим на борозды на поле:

[image: Борозды]
Изображение [Free-Photos](https://pixabay.com/photos/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1149914) с сайта [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/ru/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1149914).

Как видно — борозды параллельны. И это логично, потому что они оставляются пахотным орудием, которое имеет несколько зубьев, и которое тянет трактор в одном и том же направлении.

Даже в выражении «старый конь борозды не испортит», имеется ввиду именно то, что борозды должны быть параллельны.

Таким образом «бороздить» — это создавать параллельные друг другу прорезы, проведённые на поверхности земли.

Почему же «бороздить» ассоциируется с «пересекать в различных направлениях» в переносном смысле.

Что это за такая странная метафора? Где связь?

Как можно себе представить поле, которое борозды хаотично пересекают в разных направлениях? Как на нём можно что-то вырастить?

«...космические корабли **бороздят**...» можно вообразить, только как то, что они как-то параллельно там летают.

**Разъясните, пожалуйста, этимологию метафоры «бороздить — пересекать в различных направлениях».**

---

**Дополнение к вопросу, дабы избежать лишних ответов:**

Изначально я думал, что в этой метафоре в основе лежит сравнение борозды (как бы черты на земле) с траекторией движения чего-то, поэтому у меня возник вопрос о параллельности.

Например, есть слово чертить — проводить черту (Словаре русского языка РАН Евгеньевой):

> 1. **Проводить черту (черты), линию (линии).** Чертить палкой по земле. Чертить косые линии в тетрадке. *[Александр Федорыч] отошел к
>    окну и стал чертить пальцем по стеклу.* И. Гончаров, Обыкновенная
>    история. *Сережка рвет из рук вспотевшего Матвея циркуль и --- чертит
>    на льду окружность. Чехов, Художество.*

И есть переносный смысл (определение из того же словаря):

> **Летя, двигаясь, разрезать воздух, воду корпусом, крыльями
> и т. п. (о птице, самолете, судне и т. п.).** *Вечерние жуки поднялись с
> земли и, жужжа, стали чертить воздух.* А. К. Толстой, Князь Серебряный.
> *Корвет чертит подветренным бортом вспенившуюся поверхность океана.*
> Станюкович, Беспокойный адмирал.

Однако, по всей видимости, сравнение тут другое.

Пользователь «tum_» под моим вопросом написал в комментарии: *«Предположу, что изначально корабли „бороздили просторы океана“, например»*.

Это, скорей всего, и есть правильно происхождение метафоры.

За судном действительно на воде остаётся след, который можно сравнить со следом оставляемым пахотным орудием.

[image: След от судна]
Image by [Tudsaput Eusawas](https://pixabay.com/users/tudsaput-1932787/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1193836) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1193836)

Такое использование есть. Например, текст из Википедии: «„Летучий голландец“… обречён вечно бороздить моря». Это использование согласно данным [НКРЯ](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&sr=1&docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94aXgvbmVtLWRhbi9uZW1fZGFuXzEueG1sIzAwMDU%3D&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexgramm&mycorp=JSONeyJkb2NfaV95ZWFyX2NyZWF0ZWQiOiBbIjE4NzQxODc0Il19&kwsz=5&sem-mod1=sem&level1=0&mode=main&parent1=0&nodia=1&lex1=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&spd=10&out=normal) есть ещё в 1874 г.

Скорей всего, что эта аналогия и была основой метафоры. А «космические корабли бороздят» уже стали употреблять по аналогии с кораблями морскими, хотя они таких следов после себя не оставляют. Просто для придания возвышенного стиля речи, который закрепился за этой метафорой.

Однако другой пользователь «Третий глаз» так же верно подметил, что самолёты когда летят и космические корабли когда взлетают, тоже оставляют за собой подобный след.

[image: Самолёт]
Image by [AI Leino](https://pixabay.com/users/aileino-1030590/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1434477) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1434477)

След за самолётом тоже очень даже можно сравнить со следом от пахотного орудия. На приведённом изображении он похож на четыре борозды.

[image: Старт космического корабля]
Image by [WikiImages](https://pixabay.com/users/wikiimages-1897/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=67643) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=67643)

Так что, вероятно, происхождение метафоры от сравнения следа, оставляемого пахотным орудием на поле, со следом, оставляемым плавающими и летающими транспортными средствами в воде и в воздухе соответственно. Либо она возникла именно в отношении морских кораблей, а потом употребление расширилось на космические корабли, для придания возвышенного стиля речи, который закрепился за этой метафорой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124819/discussion-on-question-by-eagle------).

Answer (score -1):

Не нужно проецировать всё значение слова "бороздить" на другие сферы.
Например, что значит "капать на мозги"? Это значит донимать человека, говоря об одном и том же.
Давайте поищем корни этого выражения? С огромной вероятностью оно восходит к описанию пытки, в которой на зафиксированного человека сутками сутками капала вода, доводя до сумасшествия.
Всё логично. Переносный смысл ясен: систематичность, раздражающий эффект, пытка.
Но что будет, если мы подойдём к этому выражению с вашей логикой? Давайте начнём спрашивать: "Где стул? Ведь человек, привязанный для пытки, сидел на стуле! Капать на мозги разве можно только сидящему? А если я стою, то мне капать на мозги нельзя?".
На то и переносное значение! Ничего в реальности ни откуда не капает. Мозг тоже в этой ситуации не задействован. Средневековья тут тоже нет. Это просто сравнение. Метафора. Мы берём какое-то одно свойство объекта и используем его для описания другой ситуации.
Не надо искать в "бороздить" параллельности, коней, пшеничного поля и остального.
Жило-было человечество, занималось кочевым собирательством. Потом отрыло для себя земледелие, научилось пахать. Затем появились мореплаватели. Кто-то заметил, что корабль создаёт за собой в воде шлейф и сравнил его с бороздой. И так появилось значение "бороздить океан". Никто не говорил о параллельности и глубине борозд, плуге, о том, что в море потом вырастет пшеница. Просто было внешнее сходство.
Потом появились воздухоплаватели. Самолёты оставляли за собой борозду, инверсионный след. А потом появились космические корабли. И корабль он-то ведь тоже не с парусами и вёслами. Зато когда летит в небо, оставляет за собой шлейф — инверсионный след. Вот вам и борозда. Но суть не в том. Суть в том, что его уже сравнивали не с плугом и полем, а с кораблём, бороздящим просторы океана. Бороздящим — в переносном значении, то есть плавающем. А космический корабль — он плывёт в космосе. Потому и корабль. И то, что он плывёт, вовсе не значит, что в космосе плещется океан.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124820/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Comment: Насчёт непринятых ответов. Данный ваш ответ содержит зёрна истины, но вместе с тем содержит сарказм, массу эмоций и чуть ли не оскорбление в мой адрес. Вы никогда не приходили к неверным выводам в жизни? Я исходил из тех знаний, что у меня были, понял неправильно, и что? С вами такого никогда не было? Вы родились и всё сразу знали и понимали? Отредактируйте ответ, уберете эмоции, оставьте суть происхождения метафоры, и я его приму. Хоть я из комментария другого пользователя уже знал про след от морских кораблей, про след от воздушных судов, я не подумал. Так что могу принять ваш ответ.